# How to map primary key to non-primary key in EF code first?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I have two table

```
public class Table1
{
[Key]
int ID{get; set;}
Table2 table2{get; set;}
}
public class Table2
{
[Key]
int ID{get; set;}
int table1ID{get; set;}
//no instance of table i.e is relationship is uni-directional only
}
```

How can i set relationship of table1 with table2 with Table1.ID and Table2.table1ID???

Answer (score 0):

Take this for example:

```
public class Table1
{
[Key]
int ID{get; set;}
Table2 table2{get; set;}
}
public class Table2
{
[Key]
int ID{get; set;}
int table1ID{get; set;}

[ForeignKey("table1ID")]
Table1 table1{get; set;}
//no instance of table i.e is relationship is uni-directional only
}
```

This mean that, `Table2` has a `Table1` reference (`table1`) and it's foreign key is specified by the `ForeignKeyAttribute` setting it to "table1ID".

Comment: this is not what i need @RhymechaeT

Comment: I must have misunderstood. You wanted to relate these two tables trough "table1ID" right?